# What was the purpose of this diagonal 2x2 along wall?

Tags: structural, renovation

Local inspector passed me through insulation and I'm preparing to do the drywall.  When I pulled the insulation wrap on the yellow insulation part, I noticed this 2x2 sticking out diagonally.  For what purpose do builders typically do this?  Just to hold in the insulation or is it somehow structural?  Figured with a 2x2 it's probably not the latter, but just curious.[image: Unfinihsed room]

Comment: "Insulation wrap"?

Comment: This is a new room, but before this was unconditioned space.  Ergo, there was insulation wrap on that side.  I tore it off because it's no longer needed since it'll be conditioned.  There is insulation wrap around the outside perimeter of the new room (pink insulation part)

Comment: by "Insulation wrap" do you mean the paper facing? That typically would face in towards the conditioned living space.

Comment: @DrewJordan not in a basement. Best to keep vapor barriers outside in that case, or you end up with a mold situation.

Comment: @isherwood fair enough. I assumed that a roof indicated this wasn't a basement, but I guess we know what happens when you assume ;)

Comment: The inspector wanted to see wrap on the outside of the space.  I'm talking about the sheathing that has a minimal R value, not the cardboard paper.  Inspector also doesn't like cardboard because of the flammable nature of it, though he won't deny its usage.

Answer (score 5):

It was probably temporary bracing used during construction. It can be safely removed once the roof structure is complete and the walls have structural sheathing properly installed.

Comment: Yup: look at the bottom of the brace. No effort was made to integrate it with the frame.

Comment: By structural sheathing, are you just talking about plywood and tyvek?  There was room wrap on the yellow insulation side because it was unconditioned, but since I'm finishing the room I tore it off from the yellow insulation part.  County inspector was fine with that so long as the new room space has insulation wrap around the outside of it, which it does (behind pink insulation area).  The yellow insulation is no longer needed since both sides will be conditioned, but I may keep it for soundproofing.

Comment: Plywood, OSB, whatever, as long as it provides adequate diagonal bracing.